# Does anyone have Stage 4.1.1 working in Fuerte and HectorSlam

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run Stage 4.1.1 and produce a map as I did with gmapping.  With gmapping, while running stage and navigating the robot via teleoperting, I could run( rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:base_scan) and then (rosrun map_server map_saver -f map_name ) and create map. How do I produce the map with hector_slam

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149896/does-anyone-have-stage-4.1.1-working-in-fuerte-and-hectorslam/) by [msturnage](https://answers.ros.org/users/6349/msturnage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions for [use in place of gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot#Use_in_place_of_gmapping) should work.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0